# How to get Spring RestTemplate Error response in JSON format?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building restTemplate using RestTemplateBuilder and setting content-type and accept headers as application/json. When API throws an error the response is translated as HTML instead of JSON by MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.

When i manually hit the API using post-man it returns response as application/json.

I am using spring-boot version 1.5.13.RELEASE.
can you please help me to get error response as JSON.

Comment: Please add some code in order to better understand your error. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: If you use Spring boot, you should know that it offers an error handling API, using these annotations : ExpectionHandler and ControllerAdvice. You should have a look to this tutorial : https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling (first one using google). By implementing these methods, you can control what kind of beans are returned when any errors are caught by the dedicated controller.

Comment: @AnthonyBONNIER The response received in ControllerAdvice is HTML format instead of json.

Comment: private RestTemplate buildTemplate() {
 RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(requestFactory)
   .errorHandler(restTemplateResponseErrorHandler)
   .additionalMessageConverters(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter).build();
 return restTemplate;
}